# Valdiator for related entites

Tags: symfony, validation, constraints, symfony6

I have two entities, i want to have a custom [validator constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#constraints) to ensure that both entities share one value.

Example:

**Entity Region:**

- has field city
- has multiple houses as OneToMany relation
- constraint to allow only houses that have the same city

**Entity House:**

- has field city
- has one region as ManyToOne relation

your answer with any hints on how to achieve this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Since your House entity has a relationship to a Region there doesn't appear to be any reason that your House entity needs a city field. That would solve your issue without having to validate whether or not the city of a House matches the Region.

Comment: this is just a simplification, the real case is a bit more difficult. Basically i search for a validator which looks up an other entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to achieve what you want to do:

In your FormType, add an event listener on PRE_SUBMIT and add the constraint in like this:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\EqualTo;

// ...

$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    if (isset($data['cityA'])) {
        $form->add('cityB', TextType::class, [
            'constraints' => [
                new EqualTo([
                    'value' => $data['cityA'],
                    'message' => 'Must be the same as cityA',
                ]),
            ],
        ]);
    }

    // Here other constraints
});
```